# Data accessing : Django forms vs request.POST method

Tags: html, django, post, request

Can someone please explain me why is highly recommended to use Django forms to get an html object instead of direct accessing from request.POST or request.GET?

Comment: Because a Django form can perform validation, converting it to the type of the field (for example an `int`), removes boilerplate code to save to an object and a many-to-many field, uploading a file, etc.

Comment: Like in other words, in Django forms you can edit the object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between Django form and html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184096/what-is-the-difference-between-django-form-and-html-form)

Comment: @fjplaurr: I don't think these are the same. A `request.POST` (or `request.GET`) to communicate the form back, that is always a HTML form. You can decide to manually process the request (which is not advisable), or use a Django form, but a Django form has not much to do with a HTML form except that it can render one in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short**: forms make retrieving and validating less error-prone, and often will perform a lot of logic that would otherwise require (a lot of) boilerplate code.

The items in `request.POST` (or `request.GET`) are send by the browser, so you can in no way guarantee that the items will (all) be present, and in the expected format.

Indeed, `request.POST['somefield']` can raise a `KeyError` in case the POST request does not contain an key-value pair with `somefield` as key. Of course you can wrap this in a `try … except …`, but that easily will generate a large amount of code for a form with multiple items.

Even if the item is present in the `request.POST`, it is not per see in the expected format. For example if you use a number field (`<input name="somefield" type="number">`), you expect a number. But one can easily "forge" a HTTP request, where `somefield` contains `'blabla'` or `'forty-two'` instead. Django can validate the format of the fields. For an [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) for example, it will require the value to be an optional minus sign followed by a sequence of digits.

A Django form will also "clean" the values. THis means that if you use an `IntegerField`, and later you access `form.cleaned_data['somefield']`, it will not have as type a `str`ing, but an `int`. You thus do not have to do the conversion yourself *explicitly*. This means that you can immediately add the values of two `IntegerField`s together for example, whereas if you do it yourself, these are first `str`ings, and adding these together would *concatenate* the strings.

If cleaning or validating somehow fails, and a field contains an error, then a `Form` can explain what the error(s) are. You can access `form.errors`, which is a dictionary-like object that maps the names of the fields to a *list* of problems. It also makes it more convenient to list *multiple* errors. For example if a password should be at least 10 characters, and contain an uppercase, you can report *both* problems.

A [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) also makes creating and updating an object more convenient. It has a `.save()` method for that. This thus will create a new record at the database in case the `.instance` wrapped in it was not yet saved, or update the record otherwise. It furthermore also will save `ManyToManyField`s (at least if you do not set `commit=False`). This is a tricky task since in order to save the objects in the many-to-many relations, you first need to create the object at the database side.

Finally you can also use a form to easily *render* it at the HTML side. There are Django apps like [**`django-crispy-forms`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms) that can give the form another look. It thus makes it convenient to render the form, and easily change the appearance if you change your mind.